# Como criar um método que recebe de parâmetro somente uma string e retorna um tipo genérico? .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, genéricos

Como eu poderia criar um método que não precisa receber um tipo como parâmetro, apenas uma `string`, mas retornaria um tipo?

Como por exemplo:

```
public static T Guard(string guard_name) where T : class, IAuth
{
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(guard_name));
}
```

Ao invés de:

```
public static T Guard<T>(string guard_name) where T : class, IAuth
{
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(guard_name));
}
```

Então a chamada ficaria assim: `Auth.Guard("users")` ao invés de `Auth.Guard<users>()`.

Preciso de um método que receba somente uma string e não um tipo porque estou trabalhando com uma classe `ActionFilterAttribute` que a declaração é `[Autorized(string guard_name)]` e portanto não consigo utilizar um tipo nessa ocasião. Até já tentei variações como `[Autorized<users>]` por exemplo, mas por ser tratar de um atributo não consegui.

É possível?

Comment: Sim, é possível, mas não como está tentando. Está tendo algum problema tentando fazer isto? O seu retorno não parece estar usar o `T`. Pode colocar mais partes deste método?

Comment: Foi um exemplo básico, vou editar.

Comment: Pronto, editei o código.

Comment: Agora entendi melhor, isso acho que não é possível não. Vou pensar em alguma coisa pra ver se dá.

Comment: Adicionei um comentário sobre qual é a minha dificuldade, talvez haja uma outra forma ao invés de criar um método que recebe uma string e retorna um tipo.

Comment: A pergunta melhorou bem. É, estou penando em algo diferente, exatamente isto não dá, eu acho que a única forma será abrir mão do tipo genérico, que você não quer, né? Com genérico eu tenho quase certeza que é impossível. Se for, terá que dar uma voltas, talvez nem compense.

Comment: Concordo, mas se não tiver como vou ter mesmo que abrir mão do tipo genérico, o problema é que eu perderia a "dinâmica", teria que ficar declarando um novo Auth para cada tipo de usuários...

Comment: O tipo genérico funciona bem para quase toda a aplicação, apenas no `ActionFilterAttribute` que eu perco essa possibilidade, talvez eu crie um novo método para ser trabalhado somente ai.

Comment: Eu acho que teria que pensar em uma solução um pouco diferente. É possível que tenha uma solução genérica, mas ela será bem complexa. Retornar um `object` e depois fazer um *cast* provavelmente não resolverá seu problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta abordagem não é nada boa. Você está preferindo resolver uma `string` para um tipo em um atributo de autorização.

O correto seria você especificar um tipo no atributo de autorização. Alguma coisa como:

```
public class MeuAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public Type TipoClasse { get; set; }
    private SeuProjetoContexto contexto = new SeuProjetoContexto();

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var dbSet = contexto.Set(TipoClasse);
        /* Insira aqui sua lógica */
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
[MeuAuthorize(typeof(MeuModel))]
```